# Select count(*) from multiple tables in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, amazon-emr, hive-query

I have tables with the same name in 2 different schemas. What I want to do is get a count comparison in the 2 tables in the format

TableName : Count1 : Count2

How can I achieve this via Hive query?

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL:

```
select 'db1.table_name' table_name, count(col1) count1, count(col2) count2 from db1.table_name
UNION ALL
select 'db2.table_name' table_name, count(col1) count1, count(col2) count2 from db2.table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `cross join` of the count queries.

```
select t1.count1,t2.count2
from (select count(*) as count1 from tbl1) t1
cross join (select count(*) as count2 from tbl2) t2
```

Comment: Hi, I was able to get the result in the desired format but I had to set hive.strict.checks.cartesian.product to false. By default it was set as true. What is this check and am I putting anything to risk by setting it as true?

Answer (score 0):

Try full outer join

```
select tt1.cn,tt2.cn from 
    (select count(1) as cn from db1.table) tt1 
full outer join 
    (select count(1) as cn from db2.table ) tt2
on tt1.cn=tt2.cn;
```